# Make field required based on dropdown

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm hoping for some help getting around an issue I just can't seem to solve.

I need to make a field required based on a value of "new" in a select box.  I have googled, and looked at some questions here, but can't seem to get it to work in my case.

Here's my current code, which doesn't quite seem to work - I keep getting undefined for dd, and for the builder fields.

```
function selection() {
    alert("got in");
    var x;
    var number_of_input = $("#formtable select").length;
    alert(number_of_input);
    for (var i = 1; i < number_of_input; i++) {
        if (i > 1) { x = (i * 9) + 5; }
        else { x = 14 };
        alert(x);
        var name = "vnew_or_resold" + x;
        var sel = document.getElementById(name);
        var opt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
        var dd = opt.text;
        alert(dd);
        var builder = "vbuilder_name" + (x + 1);
        alert(builder);
        var build = builder.val();
        alert(build);

        if (dd == "new") {
            if (build == "") {
                alert('Mandatory');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have include the "alerts" because I need to see the values that are being inputted.

Also, the values of x in the for loop work...there are six static fields then 9 static in a table, and 9 in an unlimited number of dynamic rows.  The x is reading the correct rows - that I know for sure.  My problem really starts with the section starting at

```
var sel = document.getElementById(name);
```

Additionally, it's not actually going through all the dynamic rows, probably because either true or false are being registered - but I'm not sure.

I appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: You're expecting jQuery members to exist on plain HTML DOM elements. Wrap it up like this, maybe? `var dd = $(opt).text();` and `var builder = $("vbuilder_name" + (x + 1));` ...

Comment: You seem to be using jQuery, but most tentatively. For instance you can use [`$('#formtable select').each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) instead of a for loop. You'll want to show the HTML on which this code is supposed to act, because it would definitely help in debugging. See [mcve].